# Expect Scripting

Tags: tcl, expect

I am trying to match a text which contains the " ", from the log file. But it doesn't match. I understand that " " has got a special meaning to TCL/Expect.

Hence I tried the following, but no luck.

```
expect -ex {
            "lp -c -demail -ot\\\"firstname_surname@gmail.com\\\" /usr/local/spool/pf"
            {
               incr logged
               send_user "\r\n LOGGED #4, $logged \r\n"
            }
            timeout
```

I tried to use , \ and \\ but no luck yet.

My log file contains the following line,

```
exec [lp -c -demail -ot"firstname_surname@gmail.com"  /usr/local/spool/pf/context/ABC001-1209236.mime]
```

and I need to match that line.

Comment: Any chance you could use [`autoexpect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/autoexpect) and some silly program that prints quotes to generate the script? In my experience `autoexpect` could generate things that were difficult to hand-write.

Comment: is it possible to do it without using autoexpect?

Comment: Just noting (for anyone reading) that the description with backslashes relates to the number of backslashes (1, 2 or 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{}` quotes, which are similar to shell's single quotes. Also Tcl is sensitive to newlines, so you have to put the opening brace of a block on the previous line

```
expect {
    {lp -c -demail -ot"firstname_surname@gmail.com" /usr/local/spool/pf} {
       incr logged
       send_user "\r\n LOGGED #4, $logged \r\n"
     }
     timeout
}
```

Comment: HI Glenn, I tried using your suggestion as well, it worked for me..
Many Thanks, appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I had to do use *, temporary fix though.
But would be great if someone can tell me how to match " " in the text.

My temporary fix is,

```
expect {
         "lp -c -demail -ot*/usr/local/spool/printform" {     
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're matching something exactly, just enclose the string in `{`braces`}` itself. However, you had another problem with your code too: by putting the `-ex` outside, you were telling `expect` to match the whole lot (including your response code!) as a string. I'd be very startled if that's what your wanted! Move the flag inside the block (this works with Expect's `expect` and related commands only) and use the literal string that you're looking for instead of trying to double-guess the number of backslashes. You should get something like this:

```
expect {
    -ex {exec [lp -c -demail -ot"firstname_surname@gmail.com" /usr/local/spool/pf/context/ABC001-1209236.mime]} {
        incr logged
        send_user "\r\n LOGGED #4, $logged \r\n"
    }
    timeout
}
```

Comment: My rule of thumb is that if you are thinking about backslashing your backslashes, you've got “backslashitis” (a disease involving inflammation of the backslashes, of course) and should think about writing your code in a different way that is less prone to error. That's virtually always possible (and virtually always makes the code much clearer).